# Code coverage (c++ code execution path)

Tags: c++, path, code-coverage, execution

Let's say I have this code:

```
int function(bool b)
{
    // execution path 1
    int ret = 0;
    if(b)
    {
        // execution path 2
        ret = 55;
    }
    else
    {
        // execution path 3
        ret = 120;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I need some sort of a mechanism to make sure that the code has gone in any possible path, i.e execution paths 1, 2 & 3 in the code above.

I thought about having a global function, vector and a macro.
This macro would simply call that function, passing as parameters the source file name and the line of code, and that function would mark that as "checked", by inserting to the vector the info that the macro passed.

The problem is that I will not see anything about paths that did not "check".
Any idea how do I do this? How to "register" a line of code at compile-time, so in run-time I can see that it didn't "check" yet?

I hope I'm clear.

Comment: Just to clarify: what you label execution paths are not.  They are simply code points.  An execution path would be: enter the function, go throught the then branch, go through the return statement.  What you are asking for is branch coverage, not path coverage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually coverage utilities (such as [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html)) are supplied with compiler. However please note that they will usually give you only C0 coverage. I.e.

- C0 - every line is executed at least once. Please note that `a ? b : c` is marked as executed even if only one branch have been used.
- C1 - every branch is executed at least once.
- C2 - every path is executed at least once

So even if your tests shows 100% C0 coverage you may not catch every path in code - and probably you don't have time to do it (number of paths grows exponentially with respect to branches). However it is good to know if you have 10% C2 or 70% C2 (or 0.1% C2).

Comment: Hi Maciej, thanks for a really informative answer. My problem with it is that, and I quote from gcov's manual, "gcov works only on code compiled with GCC". You see I use VC9, Windows. Do you have any advice?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=coverage+Visual+Studion+C%2B%2B , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616977/whats-a-good-code-coverage-tool-for-use-with-visual-studio-c . I don't use VS so I cannot recommend anything specific.

Comment: According to the lcov changelog it implements branch coverage since "Fri Jan 22 2010"...

Answer (score 2):

Quite often there will be a utility supplied with your compiler to do this sort of code coverage analysis. For example, GCC has the [gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) utility.

Answer (score 2):

You need a code coverage program (gcov, bullseye, dev partner) and unit-testing (unittest++, cppunit, etc.).  You write test that will test that function.

```
TEST( UnitTestFunction )
{
    CHECK( function(true) == 55 );
    CHECK( function(false) == 120 );
}
```

Then unit tests in this case do not just check for integrity (though they still do) but they also test for coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SD C++ TestCoverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CppTestCoverage.html) for a VisualStudio compatible test coverage tool.  I believe that it in fact actually will tell you about test coverage of **a?b:c**, too.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I will not see anything about paths that did not "check".

If this means in other words that you're not only looking for the set of code points which are actually executed but also for the set of code points which have been "marked" somehow as expected to be executed to maybe finally report the difference, i might have a very [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502934/c-initializing-static-string-members) solution. It works for me on MSVC 2010 and 2013.

The approach is to make use of the pre program start initialization of static variables, but since all code points are in functions and therefore, the "static anker point" has to be put there somehow and so, the c++ feature of [delayed initialization of static function variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510/when-do-function-level-static-variables-get-allocated-initialized) has to be overcome.

This seems to be possible by adding an indirection through a template class (X) with a static member variable (progloc_) to enforce the initialization per template parameter which in turn is a wrapper struct which transports the needed information (_.*FILE*._ " at line " _.*LINE*._).

Putting this together, the most important code to achieve this could look like the following:

```
template <class T> class X {
public:
    static T progloc_;
};
template <class T> T X<T>::progloc_;

#define TRACE_CODE_POINT \
    struct ProgLocation { \
    public: \
        std::string loc_; \
        ProgLocation() : loc_(std::string(__FILE__ " at line " S__LINE__)) \
        { \
            TestFw::CodePoints::Test::imHere(loc_); \
        } \
    }; \
    TestFw::CodePoints::X<ProgLocation> dummy; \
    TestFw::CodePoints::Test::iGotCalled(dummy.progloc_.loc_);
```

The S__LINE__  - trick which is used in the ProgLocation - ctor comes from [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641427/how-to-make-preprocessor-generate-a-string-for-line-keyword).

```
#define S(x) #x
#define S_(x) S(x)
#define S__LINE__ S_(__LINE__)
```

To track, the following is used:

```
class Test
{
private:
    typedef std::set<std::string> TFuncs;
    static TFuncs registeredFunctions;
    static TFuncs calledFunctions;
public:
    static int imHere(const std::string fileAndLine)
    {
        assert(registeredFunctions.find(fileAndLine) == registeredFunctions.end());
        registeredFunctions.insert(fileAndLine);
        return 0;
    }
    static void iGotCalled(const std::string fileAndLine)
    {
        if (calledFunctions.find(fileAndLine) == calledFunctions.end())
            calledFunctions.insert(fileAndLine);
    }
    static void report()
    {
        for (TFuncs::const_iterator rfIt = registeredFunctions.begin(); rfIt != registeredFunctions.end(); ++rfIt)
            if (calledFunctions.find(*rfIt) == calledFunctions.end())
                std::cout << (*rfIt) << " didn't get called" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Maybe there are many problems connected with this approach which I don't see yet and make it inpracticable for your case, and as others pointed out, using static code analysis tools is for most situations the better solution.

EDIT:

Just found out that the provided solution has been discussed before in another context:

[non-deferred-static-member-initialization-for-templates-in-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601358/non-deferred-static-member-initialization-for-templates-in-gcc)

Comment: Thanks! Your `TRACE_CODE_POINT` example put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FILE** and **LINE** preprocessor directives:

```
#define TRACE(msg) MyTraceNotify(msg,__FILE__,__LINE__)
```

Just insert TRACE(msg) macro in your code at the places you want to track, with your custom message, and write your MyTraceNotify function.

```
void MyTraceNotify(const char *msg, const char *filename, ULONG line)
{
    /* Put your code here... */    
}
```