# C++ error C2352: 'CSchedulerDlg::Select' : illegal call of non-static member function

Tags: c++, static-methods, static-members

I am attempting to modify and improve a job scheduler application in C++

Many of the member functions are declared as `static`, and hence cannot act on the non-static member variables.

The problem arises when attempting to add additional functionality to the class. In particular, I was wondering if it was possible to call a non-static member function inside the definition of a static member function.

That is, suppose we have the member functions declarations:

```
static void email(CString message);
CRecordset * Select(CString SQL, CDatabase* dataBase);
```

I would like to call the `Select`function from within the implementation of the `email` function. But I get an error:

```
error C2352: 'CSchedulerDlg::Select' : illegal call of non-static member function
```

The error makes sense because static member functions cannot act upon the current object, but I still need to perform the `Select` function from within the `email` function. Does there exist a work around method?

The relevant code that causes the error is:

```
void CSchedulerDlg::email(CString message)
{
    CRecordset * emails = Select("some SQL query", db);
}
```

where `static CDatabase* db`is a private member variable within the class.

Comment: You did not actually show the line of code (and the relevant lines nearby) that is generating the error.   Include the code that causes the error.

Comment: @abelenky I added this

Comment: There are probably better links out there. But this is sounding like you want something similar to a singleton. Or some static function that creates any number of instances so you can call member functions from within static member functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997240/how-does-getinstance-work.

Comment: If `db` is static, why is `Select` nonstatic?

Comment: @Dan I have tried this, but it gives me other error: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class CDatabase * CSchedulerDlg::db"

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not simply provide an object for the `Select` function?

```
void CSchedulerDlg::email(CString message)
{
    CSchedulerDlg aDlg;                                      // Now you have an object.

    CRecordset * emails = aDlg.Select("some SQL query", db); // This is now a valid call.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only work around is to either make `email` non static, or add parameter `CSchedulerDlg&` to `email`:

```
 static void email(CSchedulerDlg& dlg, CString message);
```

and call `select` on `dlg` object. Both solutions are quite similar.