# How do local static objects govern compilation in C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have been learning Effective C++ and in one of the guidelines Meyer mentions that if we declare a non-local static object in one translation unit with its 
definition in another translation unit it results in undefined behaviour. This problem is fixed by writing a function that returns a reference to a local static object.

My question is that:

**How do local static objects govern compilation of various translation units?**

**How does the compiler know which translation unit to execute first?**

And my apologies if asked the question in a bit incorrect way. I hope you understood what I meant.

Comment: Quoting the actual content from the book would help, paraphrasing it when you don't even understand what it means doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/55510/487892

Comment: ***How does the compiler know which translation unit to execute first?*** This is implementation specific. There is no guarantee which is first. And that is why relying on this is UB. Returning the reference to the local static solves the issue because the static is initialized on first access to declaration of the static in the function.

Comment: Strange terminology. Objects don't 'govern compilation', and translation units are not 'executed', they are compiled. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do local static objects govern compilation of various translation units?

It's about the storage durations and privacy.

Static objects need to persist for the duration of the program execution.  They are generally placed in a different area of memory than stack or heap.  Other translation units may have static objects.  By having the compiler tag these items, the linker can throw them all into the same area  of memory.

Static objects need privacy.  When other translation units use the variable identifiers (of static objects in other modules), they can't because the variables are private.  This may produce an error or the compiler may decide to generate a copy in the other translation unit.

If you want a variable that is "global" within a translation unit, but not have other translation units see it, declare it as static.

> How does the compiler know which translation unit to execute first?

Translation units are not executed.  Functions are executed.  Functions are executed in the order specified by the program's logic, regardless of where they reside.

**By definition in the C++ language**, the `main()` function is executed first, regardless of where it lives or the order of compilation or the order of linking.

*Note:  There are other functions that are executed before main, such as C++ environment setup and constructors of global objects.  This is taken care of by the compiler and the programmer usually doesn't see it.*

**Edit 1:**
There are many discussions of how global instances of classes or structures are initialized, and when they are initialized.

For example, a constructor of a global class may call `cout` to print something.  In order to make this work, the I/O streams need to be initialized before this constructor is called.  So now the `cout` object needs to be initialized before a global object.

There are other interesting issues as well, but that discussion is to broad for this answer.