# Thread safety of local static array in C99

Tags: c, arrays, thread-safety, c99, static-variables

The following is thread safe since each array element is accessed by only one thread (including the real world part not shown here):

```
static bool myArray[THREAD_COUNT] = {false}; // Only used in DoSomething()

void DoSomething(uint8_t threadIndex)
{
   myArray[threadIndex] = true;
   // Real world function is more complex
}
```

Now consider the following code:

```
void DoSomething(uint8_t threadIndex)
{
   static bool myArray[THREAD_COUNT] = {false};
   myArray[threadIndex] = true;
   // Real world function is more complex
}
```

Is this function threadsafe too (especially considering the array initialization that takes place at first call of the function, not at startup)?

Comment: A global variable or a local `static` variable are basically the same. All you have changed is really just the scope (practically speaking). And initialization of local `static` variables is thread-safe.

Comment: Are we sure that initialization of a **static** local variable is made upon the first call to the subroutine? I'm not - can somebody confirm?

Comment: @linuxfan I don't think there is a standard requirement about it as it doesn't affect the semantics. But the common implementation is to place the initialized variables with static storage into the dedicated `.data` section in the binary during compile time. Actually it wouldn't make sense to force the compiler to include a *one time* initialization code into a function. Such a code will require some extra tracking (some other static variables?). Update: Hey, look, there **is** a standard requirement...

Comment: "considering the array initialization that takes place at first call of the function, not at startup" - That's wrong. Initialisation of static objects is completed before `main` is called. An assignment is not an initialisation.

Comment: I would not bet on this. Use C11 `_Thread_local` to be on the safe side. As a personal note: I'd rather have the array outside the function body, properly documented.

Comment: @Olaf Where did I get that idea? Are local statics in C++ initialized on first function call?

Comment: @Silicomancer, nops, local statics are also initialized at program startup in C++

Comment: @Silicomancer: This is C, not C++! Therefore I commented in C context. I'm not a clairvoyant, so how would I know why you thought that?

Comment: @KeineLust Here they say something different: http://stackoverflow.com/q/55510/1421332

Comment: @Olaf I know, just trying to understand the differences

Comment: @Silicomancer: The actual question is: why do you assume two different languages have to behave identical= (retorical question, let's not discuss this further)

Comment: @Silicomancer I don't think there's anything contrary in the the question you linked to. An answer by Arkadiy quotes the same from C++ standard and other answers, albeit experimental in nature, says/shows the same.

Comment: @P.P. Sorry, you lost me. All those answers behind the link say that static locals in C++ are initialised on usage. Not on startup and not on function call. While for C99 you quoted that it is done at/before startup. In which way is this compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's safe. All objects with static storage duration are initialized *before* program startup. That means even before any threads come into play.

[5.1.2 Execution environments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#5.1.2):

> Two execution environments are defined: freestanding and hosted. In
>   both cases, program startup occurs when a designated C function is
>   called by the execution environment. **All objects with static storage
>   duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) before
>   program startup.** The manner and timing of such initialization are
>   otherwise unspecified. Program termination returns control to the
>   execution environment.

(emphasis mine).

C99 didn't have the concept of threads. But that's how I'd interpret the above quote from the standard.

Comment: OT: Is it my impression or people still prefers POSIX threads over C11 threads?

Comment: Interesting. Wait... were did I get the idea local statics are initialized on first function call? Is it that way in C++?

Comment: You should update your links to the current standard (final draft actually): http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: @Olaf The question is specifically about C99. So, it's appropriate to quote C99 (draft).

Comment: @KeineLust C11 threads support isn't widely available (notably glibc doesn't provide it yet). So, most still prefer POSIX threads I guess.

Comment: @P.P.: Sorry, I oversaw the c99 tag at the question.

Comment: @Silicomancer C++ standard says something quite similar too. From C++14 (N3797 draft): *Every object of static storage duration is zero-initialized at program startup before any other initialization takes place. In some cases, additional initialization is done late*.