# Why gcc accepts initializing the static variable within the method to the field of the object?

Tags: c++, object, gcc

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int obj_field;

    MyClass(int val) : obj_field(val) {}

    void myMethod() {
        static int my_static_var = obj_field;  // <--- Why is this okay?
        // ... 
    }
};
```

I was in depth convinced this is wrong and should not compile because I was sure they can only be initialized to constexpr (assuming values are initialized before the execution begins). To my surprise, it compiles no errors with gcc 9.4.0, C++17. Would it be able to postpone the initialization of the static variable till the first call or undefined behavior is more likely?

I understand that if it would ever work, static value will probably be picked from the first object that called the method.

Comment: _"Would it be able to postpone the initialization of the static variable till the first call"_ - Yes.

Comment: *"I was in depth convinced this is wrong and should not compile."* -- Why? Static variables within functions (both member and non-member functions) are perfectly standard.

Comment: Static local variables - _"... are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration..."_ see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Comment: @JaMiT because I was sure they can only be initialized to constexpr

Comment: It maybe gets more obvious if you do this: `void myMethod(int x) { static int my_static_var = x; }` since a variable can only be initialized once, it _must_ be initialized when the function is first called.

Comment: @RichardCritten this is the answer. You can add this answer that I would accept, or otherwise I can also delete the question.

Comment: `static` controls the storage duration of the object.  You still initialize like normal.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas *"because I was sure they can only be initialized to constexpr"* -- Maybe you should mention that in your question? (Not that I know where that idea comes from. But it would at least partially explain the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would it be able to postpone the initialization of the static variable till the first call

That is in fact the point when a *local* static variable is initialized. More specifically, initialization happens when the execution reaches the point of declaration for the first time.

> or undefined behavior is more likely?

There's no UB in the example.

> Why gcc accepts initializing the static variable within the method to the field of the object?

Because doing so is well formed.

Comment: May also want to add that even in multi-threading, the static variable is guaranteed to only be initialized once.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's enough of a side note that I find it enough to have your comment. Side note on the side note: This guarantee was added in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

> (assuming values are initialized before the execution begins)

This assumption is off on (probably) two points.

First, the timing of initializing a `static` variable inside a function is different from that of a `static` variable at namespace scope. While global statics are (mostly) initialized before `main` executes (which I'm guessing is what you were thinking of), a local static is not initialized until its definition would be executed. This means that it is not initialized until (at least) the first time the function is called.

Second, [execution does not begin with the `main` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4783404). The initialization of global `static` variables is split into [two stages](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables). The first stage handles the constant expression initialization that you are aware of. The second stage is for those variables that need to execute code for their construction. The second stage can finish before the `main` function starts. (There is some leeway that allows the second stage to bleed over the start of `main`.)

In fact, the ability to execute code when initializing a global `static` variable is a key ingredient in the [static-order-fiasco](/questions/tagged/static-order-fiasco). Even better, one way to resolve some static order fiascoes is to control initialization order by wrapping `static` variable definitions inside getter functions. This ensures that the variable is initialized the first time the function is called, which necessarily will be before the first time the variable's value is used. So you could say that in your question, you have solved a problem that you did not know existed. :)

*For those who like to experiment,* here is a simple example showing that a `static` variable at namespace scope can be initialized with a non-constant expression.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

static const auto start_time =
    std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

int main() {
    std::cout << "Program started at: " << std::ctime(&start_time) << "\n";
}
```

*To directly address the question:*
Yes, initialization of `my_static_var` is postponed until the first call to `myMethod()`, and the value will be from the `*this` object of that call.

**See also** [When do function-level static variables get allocated/initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510/when-do-function-level-static-variables-get-allocated-initialized)